# How to remove multi index from dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, multi-index

I have a data frame

```
          purchase_count
Scrips     1STCUS  20MICRONS  21STCENMGM  3MINDIA
Client_id                   
A100027     NaN      NaN        NaN         NaN 
A100074     NaN      NaN        NaN         NaN 
A100077     NaN      NaN        NaN         NaN
A100088     NaN      NaN        NaN         NaN 
A100091     NaN      NaN        NaN         NaN
```

This dataframe is a result of pd.pivot_table and is getting created as multi index .Also output of df_matrix.columns is

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['purchase_count'], ['1STCUS', '20MICRONS', '21STCENMGM', '3IINFOTECH', '3MINDIA']])
```

How to remove multi indexing in which I want my output to be

```
            1STCUS  20MICRONS  21STCENMGM  3MINDIA                  
A100027     NaN      NaN        NaN         NaN 
A100074     NaN      NaN        NaN         NaN 
A100077     NaN      NaN        NaN         NaN
A100088     NaN      NaN        NaN         NaN 
A100091     NaN      NaN        NaN         NaN
```

Comment: What is your pivot_table command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

Another solution should be changed `pivot_table`, obviosly remove `[]` around `['purchase_count']`